# DisplayLink adapter only works immediately after driver install

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, displaylink

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo E580. Upon installing the [DisplayLink driver (version 4.4)](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/file?id=1261), my StarTech DK30CH2DPPD USB-C dock works perfectly, passing through video to both my DisplayPort and HDMI monitors. However, if I log out and log back in, reboot, or anything, the DisplayPort monitor disappears permanently until I uninstall the driver, reboot, and re-install the driver.

- It appears the reason the HDMI monitor continues to work as that port isn't actually managed by the DisplayLink protocol, rather it's powered by the USB-C DisplayPort Alt Mode. It shows up in xrander as a DisplayPort monitor even though it's connected through HDMI.
- Ironically, when it's working, the real DisplayPort monitor shows up as a DVI monitor, which is expected as that's how all DisplayLink monitors are presented to the OS.
- When it's working, `xrandr --list-providers` lists 2 providers. After the monitor disappears, it only lists the Intel GPU.

I have tried numerous things, from rebooting with the dock connected, disconnected, connected but with monitors disconnected, as well as restarting `dlm.service`. Is there something I'm missing to make this thing reliably work?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I found a solution here https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/92

Where you have to insert the following text in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

```
Section "Device"
Identifier "intel"
Driver "modesetting"
Option "kmsdev" "/dev/dri/card0"
Option "PageFlip" "off"
Option "SWCursor" "on"
Option "ShadowFB" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "USB3"
BusID "USB"
Driver "modesetting"
Option "kmsdev" "/dev/dri/card1"
Option "PageFlip" "off"
Option "SWCursor" "on"
Option "ShadowFB" "true"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier "USB3"
BusID "USB"
Driver "modesetting"
Option "kmsdev" "/dev/dri/card2"
Option "PageFlip" "off"
Option "SWCursor" "on"
Option "ShadowFB" "true"
EndSection
```

Now you don't have to uninstall & install the driver again after every logout/shutdown.

Answer (score -1):

1. Thanks to this article:
   Unistall the x11 driver and install it back -
2. Uninstall instructions:
   https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12670/how-to-cleanly-remove-x11
   This answer shows up high in search for google "remove X11 ubuntu" so I thought it would help to update it for Ubuntu 18.04

   sudo apt purge 'x11-*'
   sudo apt autoremove

check to see what files or folders are there -

```
sudo ls -alF /tmp
```

remove as needed -

```
sudo rm -r /tmp/.X11-unix  
sudo rm -r /tmp/.XIM-unix
```

3. Check if driver is still there

   dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core
4. Driver download latest
   https://www.startech.com/en-us/audio-video-products/usb32hdpro#support--section-downloads

install instructions:
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649

5. Restart computer
6. Login ubuntu in wayland mode
7. Normally as I last saw Xorg was not displayed in this list
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637005/how-to-check-if-x-server-is-running
8. See  list of USB ports connected to devices.

   lsusb -d 17e9:
   ps -e | grep tty
9. Then I connected the cabel and it detected the monitor
10. For next time always put computer in lock mode before leaving anywhere.